# PHP4 for Apache 2.2.9 in Ubuntu server 8.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, php4

I recently moved from a windows based development environment to an ubuntu one. I need to have both PHP4 and PHP5 available (PHP4 is a company requirement, so not much I can decide about it). My problem is that I can't install PHP4, as it's not available as a package an it seems that the only way to get it would be to compile it. Can you point me to a good resource or tutorial on how to compile and install PHP4. I need to be able to easily switch between both versions, a là WAMPSERVER (If not possible I'll set for PHP4). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the real problem is that your company is requiring you to run PHP4, which is a EOLd product. That means no more security fixes. I would be *very* afraid of deploying something like that.

That being said, you could probably run both by running one as CGI and the other as an apache module, or both as CGI and mapping CGI support to different versions based on IP or vhost. [This article](http://blog.thembid.com/2007/06/21/how-to-run-php-4-and-5-in-ubuntu-without-cgi/) describes running both 4 and 5 under different IPs as apache modules, but it is for Ubuntu 6.06.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

php4 packages seems to be available in dapper.

You could add dapper's repos to your sources.list just the time you need to install php4 :-) (that's not very clean, but it might be more clean than somethingelse).

(Or you can set source preferences by package but i don't know how to do it, i just know that it exists in Debian, so it should exists in Ubuntu too).

PS: sorry for my english.